# Windows server 2003 : requirements for website deployment

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, windows-server-2003

I have one ASP.NET website having following associated components

1. ASP.NET framework 3.5
2. MS Chart
3. AJAX Components
4. Connection with external webservice for data
5. Oracle 10g Enterprise edition

I am going to deploy all web site component, database, email server and FTP service under same hardware.

Here I would like to know what are the required configuration of Windows Server 2003 to meet above requirements, like RAM, Processor, etc.

Please trigger me if I missed inputs.

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: More information is needed to determine this. What is the expected server load/concurrent user count?

Answer (score 0):

It depends more on the load, the size, the complexity of the app and the performance expected, than in the components.

I mean: You can run this requirements with modest hardware, but if your app in heavy or your users are thousands, you will need another beast.